# How can I improve my LogConverter?

Tags: python

this is my first piece of code in Python. It's supposed to convert a .json file into json objects.
The .json file looks like this:

edit: I have to depend on the string "Title_" to separate my 'columns'.
The 'items' are random strings, but each title has exactly the same amount of items.

```
[
  "Title_1",
  "Item1",
  "Item2",
  "Item3",
  "Title_2",
  "Item1",
  "Item2",
  "Item3",
  "Title_3",
  "Item1",
  "Item2",
  "Item3",
]
```

The end result should look like a list of these:

```
{"somekey":"item1","anotherkey":"item1", "yetanotherkey":"item1"}
etc...
```

This is the magnificent piece of code I came up with:

```
def convertJSON(file_name):
'''
:param file_name:
:return: single log_messages JSON object with JSON array of log_messages    
as value
'''
  log = open(file_name, 'r')
  logaslist = list(log)
  #remove opening and closing brackets
  preppedlogaslist = logaslist[1:-1]
  templist = []
  listoflists = []
  #loop trough list and park items in listoflists
  for t in preppedlogaslist:
    if "Title_" in t:
        if listoflists is not None and len(templist) is not 0:
            listoflists.append(templist)
            templist = []
    else:
        templist.append(t[2:-3])
  listoflists.append(templist)
  #create JSON object
  agedayslist = listoflists[0]
  ageweekslist = listoflists[1]
  messagelist = listoflists[2]
  jsondict = []
  for i in range(len(messagelist)):
    jsondict.append({'age_days':agedayslist[i],'age_weeks':ageweekslist[i],
    'message':messagelist[i]})
return json.dumps(jsondict)
```

I'm sure this can be improved. 
Big thanks to anyone who nudges this little babyworm in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehensions and the [**`json.load`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) function from the standard library.

```
>>> import json
>>> f = json.loads('["Title_1","Item1","Item2","Item3","Title_2","Item1","Item2","Item3","Title_3","Item1","Item2","Item3"]')
>>> dict((item.lower()+'key', item) for item in f if not item.startswith('Title_'))
{'item1key': 'Item1', 'item2key': 'Item2', 'item3key': 'Item3'}
```

Comment: I tried json.loads but for some reason it returned an error. Thanks for responding, I edited my question a little bit.

Comment: @WimBerchmans in your case it should be `json.load` since you are loading content of file

Comment: Got it, thanks. I failed to specify this in my original question but I have to depend on the string "Title_" to separate my 'columns'. The 'items' are all random strings, but each title has exactly the same amount of items.